# Internal server error in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, badboy

Am trying to load a test transaction in my server with JMeter.
I created the script using Badboy software and tried to run it on JMeter but it gave me a internal server error.

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1

```
Sample Start: 2017-08-04 17:33:21 SGT
Load time: 17 
Connect Time: 0 
Latency: 16 
Size in bytes: 477 Sent
bytes:0 
Headers size in bytes: 445 
Body size in bytes: 32 Sample
Count: 1 
Error Count: 1 
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text Response
code: 500 
Response message: Internal Server Error
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 09:33:11 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
```

$WSEP:

```
Content-Length: 26851 
Set-Cookie: oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=-iyyeawi7n; Path=/BelsizeWeb
Set-Cookie: oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=-iyyeawi7m; Path=/BelsizeWeb
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie,set-cookie2" 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
```

HTTPSampleResult fields:

```
ContentType: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

I tried using blazemeter recording software as well but even though there was no server error, there was no recorded transaction or logins in my server logs.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Internal server error is coming from server, can never be "in JMeter"
It probably means that your JMeter request does not match what server expects(e.g. not authenticated, out of order, missing headers, rong body format etc). So you need to debug your script and see what you are sending wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [HTTP Status Code 500 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

   > The HTTP 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
   >
   > This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Oftentimes server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

   So first of all you need to check your application logs, most likely you will get more detailed information from them.
2. Looking into [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

   ```
   Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT 
                        ^^^^ what?
   ```

   Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan and setting `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` property in *user.properties* file
3. In the majority of cases you cannot just record and replay a modern web applications actions as they widely use dynamic parameters for client state tracking and security reasons. So you need to design your test like:

   - Open Login Page (normally GET request)

     - Extract dynamic parameters using [JMeter PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
   - Perform Login (normally POST request) providing credentials and the aforementioned extracted dynamic parameters values

   The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) and given you properly implement it you should be able to replay your test scenario using JMeter (use [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and 1 virtual user to validate your test)